# Execute cupsenable inside a script by all users without prompting for password

Tags: linux, printing, sudoers

I have read the other answers to my question to make sure this is not a duplicate, but they don't work because my script `/usr/local/bin/FuncionaYaImpresoraDeLosInfiernos.sh` keeps prompting for a password:

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> sudo /usr/sbin/cupsenable Deskjet_1050_J410

Even when my sudoers file includes these desperate attempts:

> frustrateduser ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/cupsenable
>
> frustrateduser ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/FuncionaYaImpresoraDeLosInfiernos.sh

And I have done this, in pure anger and frustration:

> sudo chmod 7777 /usr/local/bin/FuncionaYaImpresoraDeLosInfiernos.sh

I don't want to completely carry on with the full destruction of another keyboard this time, but this one is already missing two keys after the last 3 hours of confrontation, and I beg for a solution. The mouse is doing well but it already has a crack in the plastic case and it might not hold much longer. Thanks.